# Is the Chappa'ai vortex ionized or toxic?

Tags: analysis, stargate

In the Stargate universe, the vortex from the naqahdah disc which occurs once an address is correctly dialed emits a fluid-like substance. Is this substance an ionized radiation or a chemical exposed to the breathable oxygen?

The question: 'Is the Chappa'ai vortex ionized or toxic?'

Comment: It's not a fluid at all...it just appears that way.

Answer (score 3):

Neither. The unstable vortex is not chemical or elemental matter, it's explicitly described as energy. It is also not ionized radiation as we know it, as a source of ionized radiation would require protection for anyone near by. If the vortex was ionized radiation every gate team standing in front of it would experience high levels of radiation 
Exposure and poisoning on every gate event.

No technical or scientific details on what kind of energy the vortex is was provided. All we really know is that it is highly destructive to matter and energy in its path.

Comment: & quite localised - I'm sure I recall 'half people' after standing in the way [but it's been a long time since I saw an episode so I may have invented that 'factoid']

Comment: No, you are correct. It destroys any matter it contacts and nothing more. Many a smoking pair of feet. They also used it to destroy objects, ships and bombs a few times. The event horizon has a similar effect, but that's only if the stargate is shut down with someone half way through. That's more of a transporter issue.

Comment: It also has a similar effect on anyone trying to go through the "wrong way" (ie: they go in and never come out.)  The wormhole only works in one direction at a time, which is why they always need to shut it down and redial from the other side to go home.  (also why SGC sends those robots through to confirm the presence of a DHD on the other side.)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screen]

Per the Ultimate Visual Guide, it is...unspecified.

The "liquid" is an event horizon of an "energized matter stream".    Could it be radiated?  Perhaps, but given there are no specific precautions taken when approaching it (and that it is designed to transport humanoids) it is safe to assume it is not unsafe levels of radiations.  Is it ionized?   Perhaps, but this is not addressed.

Specifically, they are simply identified as "quantum particles".    Techno-babble I believe.